# Incorrect results when calculating difference between number of days

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am using the following code snippet to find difference between two dates and the result is off by one day:

```
NSString * dateString = @"2011-11-26" ;
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];  
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];  
NSDate * today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate * futureDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];;
NSCalendar * gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags =  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents * components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:today toDate:futureDate options:0];
NSLog(@"Number of days: %i",[components day]);
[today release];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Number of days: 6 from above code. Actually it is 7 days from today Nov 19th 2011.

[image]

**Updated:** The following works fine. Am I repeating code ?

```
            NSString * dateString = @"2011-11-26" ;
            NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];  
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];  
            NSDate * today = [NSDate date];

            NSCalendar * greg = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
            NSUInteger uf = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
            NSDateComponents * comp = [greg components:uf fromDate:today];
            today = [greg dateFromComponents:comp];

            NSDate * futureDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];;
            NSCalendar * gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
            NSUInteger unitFlags =  NSDayCalendarUnit;
            NSDateComponents * components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:today toDate:futureDate options:0];

           NSLog(@"Number of days: %ld",[components day]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple's docs about the `components:fromDate:toDate:` say this:

> The result is lossy if there is not a small enough unit requested to hold the full precision of the difference.

This means that it would like to tell you the difference is "6 days and 12 hours and 31 minutes and 2 seconds..." but you've only asked for days, so you get back 6. My suggestion would be to round today's date to midnight first, so that it's an integer number of days away from the target date.

Edit: you can do this rounding by asking NSCalendar to give you the `NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit` of today's date, then re-constructing a date from those components. (Using `components:fromDate:` and `dateFromComponents:` respectively.)

Comment: Thanks Jesse, I have updated my question with code. Can you please take a look at it and see if there is efficient way of doing it by not repeating code which I am I think.

Comment: Your code looks fine, though you probably don't need 2 calendars; just re-use the NSCalendar you create for the first calculation. You might also want to break that up into methods like `dateAtMidnightForDate:` or similar. Both the NSCalendar and NSDateFormatter can be expensive to create over and over, so you might want to create them once and store them in an instance variable, for example, if you see them showing up in profiling.

Comment: "Both the NSCalendar and NSDateFormatter can be expensive to create over and over," - very true, I hadn't realised just how expensive NSCalendar instantiation was until recently.